# Erratic mouse screen behavior with Wayland on Gentoo

Tags: gnome, mouse, gentoo, wayland

I have an HP laptop that has Gentoo installed on it. Right after a successful OS installation, I put GNOME on it. It uses Wayland on the back (not sure what compositor) and default theme (I presume Adwaita).

What happened is that after the GNOME installation, the laptop became almost unusable: the mouse cursor was moving by itself erratically and mouse clicks started happening also by themselves.

I tried to change the mouse, but it didn't work. Removing the mouse fixes it temporarily, but then TouchPad becomes stuck and mouse cursor freezes.

The laptop also has a touch screen. I'm not dual booting on it. Another laptop I have with Gentoo + X + GNOME, but without a touch screen, has no such issues.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev c8)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
```

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

EDIT:

I start to suspect that this is Wayland + touch screen issue. ;-)

I have qanother laptop with Gentoo + Wayland, bit not the touch screen and it is operating fine.

Comment: Is the sluggishness limited to GNOME or are console sessions impacted as well? Have you tried blacklisting the trackpad kernel module?

Comment: @Ginnungagap, I don't think so. Everything worked before installing GNOME. And no - I didn't try that.

Comment: Is there some explicit need for `wayland`?  You can rebuild the entire system without wayland.  If the sluggishness still exists after removing wayland support then you have ruled out wayland as the issue.

Comment: Followup: See [Section 5.2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/touchscreen) in this ArchWiki entry. If you need help removing wayland let me know here.

Comment: @eyoung100, no there is no explicit need for it. But rebuilding the system is just time consuming... I would love to solve all this though. Googling shows that I'm not lone who experience this from Wayland,

Comment: Welcome to Gentoo.  Trade compile time for fine-tuning.  As the Wiki entry in my last comment lays out, removing Wayland support will force the use of plain-old X11 which should resolve the issue.  You won't have to rebuild the whole system, just those packages that have the `wayland` USE flag attached.  See `man emerge`, specifically `--newuse`

Comment: @eyoung100, please check my edit...

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Quoting:

> Wayland does not currently have a known method to lock touching to a specific display in any environment other than sway (or wlroots-based supported compositors). There are tools such as weston-touch-calibrator, but Gnome Wayland uses Xwayland leaving the calibrator unable to locate any touchscreen.
> ...
> The current known method to use touchscreens in a multi-head setup is to force Gnome or KDE to use X11.

### Fix

1. From a terminal outside of the Desktop Environment, issue an `emerge -av app-portage/ufed`
2. As root, issue `ufed`
3. To solve the immediate issue, find the `wayland` USE Flag.  Highlight it, and hit spacebar a few times, until the option is a minus sign.
4. Hit ESC, and answer Y to save the updated flag.
5. This has written `-wayland` to `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

To complete the update, issue `emerge --update --deep --ask --verbose --newuse --with-bdeps=y @world`  Short version: `emerge -uDavN --with-bdeps=y @world`.

This should rebuild every package that has `wayland` as a USE Flag.

### Further Fine-Tuning

`ufed` is your friend in situations like the above and many more.  This tool, short for USE Flag EDitor allows you to safely edit your `make.conf` file, ensuring no errors occur.  Feel free to add and remove flags after fixing your issue always using the command given above to rebuild after your changes.

Comment: so what is the differfence between `ufed` and manually changing the `USE-flags`?

Comment: There is none, but there are numerous USE Flags and this helps with formatting and error checking.